# CMake cross compile with ncurses

Tags: c++, cmake, cross-platform

I'm working with an already setup CMake crosscompiler provided by NVIDIA for an embedded arm system. As I want to get the users keyboard inputs without enter pressed and not waiting for it, I use the ncurses lib.

Building for my host system works like expected. But when I want to build for the embedded system it complains about:

> fatal error: ncurses.h No such file or directory

I changed the CMakeList to link the ncurses lib:

```
set(LIBRARIES
    ...
    ncurses
)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${LIBRARIES})
```

As I understood CMake cannot find a suitable version of ncurses for the arm target plattform. How can I provide the right library?

To build for the target I use the following command:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
      -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/path/to/cmake/Toolchain.cmake \
      -DPDK:STRING=/path/to/PLATTFORM_PDK\
       ..
```

Within this PLATTFORM_PDK folder there are folders like include or lib-target.
Is it enough to place the ncurses.h in the folder include?

Comment: Libraries is just a variable. It doesn't tell CMake to link with any libraries. Show the full code.

Comment: I changed the question.

Comment: Show your toolchain file.